# Using lists to sort

Tags: python, sorting

```
nonpalidrome=[]
for word in lowers:
    if len(word)>=7:
        if word[2:-2:1]==word[2:-2:-1]:
            if word[1]!=word[-1]:
                nonpalidrome.append(word)
```

This is what i have so far what i am trying to do is:

> By filtering the lowers list, create a list of the words which satisfy
>   all three of the following criteria, printing the list when you are
>   done:
>
> the word is at least 7 characters long; the middle of the word,
>   skipping the first and last letters, is a palindrome (same forward as
>   backward); the word itself is not a palindrome.

I feel like im really close.. what am i missing

Comment: What problem are you having? What doesn't work about this code?

Comment: It works but i get an empty list

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: You approved the non-edit? Why did you feel that was an improvement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this:

```
for word in lowers :
   if len(word) >=7 and word[1:-1] == word[1:-1][::-1] and word [0] != word[-1]:
       nonpalindrome.append(word)
```

use `[1:-1]` to get the middle of the word, use `[::-1]` to get the reversed string to match whether it is a palindrome or not :

```
In [172]: word='ballooned'

In [173]: word[1:-1] 
Out[173]: 'alloone'

In [174]: word[1:-1][::-1]
Out[174]: 'enoolla'

In [175]: word[::-1]
Out[175]: 'denoollab'
```

or using a list comprehension:

```
non_palindrome=[x for x lowers if len(x)>=7 and x[1:-1]==x[1:-1][::-1] and x[0] != x[-1] ]
```

Comment: `[s for s in lowers if len(s) >= 7 and s[1:-1] != s[1:-1][::-1] and s[0] != s[-1]]`

Answer (score 1):

Since your problem is that your resulting list is empty, that means one of your conditions isn't working:

```
if len(word)>=7:

if word[2:-2:1]==word[2:-2:-1]:

if word[1]!=word[-1]:
```

The first thing I would try is to add `print` statements after each one to narrow down the problem:

```
nonpalidrome=[]
for word in lowers:
    print("Got word " + word)
    if len(word)>=7:
        print("len(word) >= 7")
        if word[2:-2:1]==word[2:-2:-1]:
            print("word[2:-2:1]==word[2:-2:-1]")
            if word[1]!=word[-1]:
                print("word[1]!=word[-1]")
                nonpalidrome.append(word)
```

Now you can look for print statements that don't appear, and you'll know which `if` statement isn't having your expected results.

By the way, your code is much more complicated than it needs to be. Why not loop through the string instead of comparing hard-coded indexes like 1 and 2?